# WKWebView does not have a context menu on cataylst

Tags: ios, swift, macos

So I am trying to get my ios app working nice on macos using catalyst.  I got a problem with my WkWebView, I kind of expect there to be some kind of context menu, but there is none.  Like on the iPad if you highlight some text, it will give context menu of sorts to copy it etc.  But on catalyst there is nothing.  I can't find anything on Google about this.  My code to create the webview is this.

```
func createWebView() {
     let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
     configuration.setURLSchemeHandler(PrayerAssetHandler(), forURLScheme: "x-file")

     webview = WKWebView(frame: webContentView.bounds, configuration: configuration)
     self.webContentView.addSubview(webview!)
     webview?.autoresizingMask = webContentView.autoresizingMask
     webview!.navigationDelegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works... but somehow bit weird - after you make selection just right-mouse click *outside* selection, and you'll get contextual menu for the selection =)

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.3

Comment: Well that is an obvious bug then, because naturally I click on my selection when I want to copy it.